# How can I cheaply set up a small studio and learn how to use it?

Tags: studio-lighting, diy, studio, studio-setup, low-budget

Recently I've been thinking a lot about how I can increase the production value of my photos and films. I've come to the conclusion that I need to learn how to set up a small studio and how to use light more efficiently. I need to learn the key aspects/principles of these two things.

So, starting at a very basic level, how do I go about setting up a studio? What kinds of different materials do I need? What kind of lights do I need? Which of these are easy and/or cheaper to make myself, with easily accessible materials, than to buy/use professional equipment?

I'd like to be able to set up the most important/essential stuff myself, preferrably without having to buy a lot of expensive new equipment. So what are the most important things to know? What are some resources you can recommend for further reading? Basically: where do I begin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What equipment is required for a home studio?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/755/what-equipment-is-required-for-a-home-studio)

Comment: what sort of photography?  portraits, products?  you can learn a lot about light from natural light, are you referring to needing to learn about studio lighting, camera flash? For general questions about studio setup, see the "tag wiki" - http://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/studio-setup/info

Answer (score 5):

#### Simple

You will probably want to think about 3 things (assuming you have a camera already!)

I'm concentrating on low-cost options.

- Background

  - A white-painted wall is a great start
- Lights

  - A single strobe with a stand and a shoot-through umbrella is a good start here. You will need a way to trigger it - a cable is functional and cheap.
- Props

  - Something for your subject(s) to sit on really helps.  A simple bar stool gives good posture and makes people more comfortable than standing

All of these can be improved / upgraded / build on as time and money allow.  Also, once you have a bit of practice under your belt you will start to work out how you would like to improve things: another light, different backgrounds, etc.

I suggest you also check out this question: [What equipment is required for a home studio?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/755/what-equipment-is-required-for-a-home-studio/852#852)

Comment: Very good answer, but it doesn't quite fit my needs as I do a lot of (mostly even) video work. So static lights are a must.

Would reflectors be a better start for this?

Comment: Scott Kelby also had some nice low cost tips in his Digital photography books - for example using common shower curtain to get diffused light etc.

Comment: @burnso, yes. reflectors give you great flexibility for the money (they're also light and don't break!).  I'm not a big on video, though, so I hope someone more experienced can help.

Comment: @burnso - for video you need continuous light, and as far as I know, those are not cheap, so a reflector could probably be a very good idea.